# Arrays en Java, ¿Como usarlos?

Tags: java, array

Antes que nada agradecer a los que se tomen su tiempo para ayudarme a resolver este breve problema que tengo en java/eclipse, intentaré ser breve y conciso.

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa programa que calcule la suma de valores par/impar del array. Para decidir entre calcular con valores pares o impares se decide con variable booleana llamada sumar_pares: p -> valores pares. i -> valores impares

este es mi codigo :

```
                Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                int arreglo[] = new int [10];
                int conteo_pares=0, conteo_impares=0;
                
                System.out.println("Llenar Arreglo");
                
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                    System.out.print((i+1)+ ". Digite un numero: ");
                    arreglo[i] = sc.nextInt();
                    
                    if(arreglo[i] % 2==0) { //Si el numero es par
                        conteo_pares++;
                    }
                    else { //Si el numero es impar
                        conteo_impares++;
                    }
                }
                
                //Crear los arreglos siguientes
                int par[] = new int[conteo_pares]; //Creamos el arreglo para almacenar los numeros pares
                int impar[] = new int[conteo_impares]; //y ahora los numeros impares
                
                conteo_pares=0;
                conteo_impares=0;
                
                //Almacenamos los numeros pares en su arreglo y los impares tambien
                for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
                    if(arreglo[i] % 2==0) { //Si el numero es par
                        par[conteo_pares] = arreglo[i];
                        conteo_pares++;
                    }
                    else { // Si el numero es impar
                        impar[conteo_impares] = arreglo[i];
                        conteo_impares++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.print("\nArreglo pares: ");
                for(int i=0; i<conteo_pares;i++) {
                    System.out.print(par[i]+" - ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
                
                System.out.print("\nArreglo impares: ");
                for(int i=0; i<conteo_impares;i++) {
                    System.out.print(impar[i]+" - ");
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
```

me funciona a la hora de separar los  valores del array par y impar, todo perfecto ,pero como ejecuto la funcion booleana llamada sumar_pares? o impares? es algo que no entendi en el enunciado del problema, ¿como lo puedo implementar a mi programa?

Comment: aunque no lo creas, ya hiciste todo.. inclusive, separar en pares o impares.. con lo cual, que problema tenes en particular? no sabes como escribir una funcion?

Comment: quiero ahora poder decir , sumame los valores impares o sumame los valores pares , pero eso se tiene que decidir con una variable booleana llamada sumar_pares: p -> valores pares. i -> valores impares ,no se como implementar ese metodo

Comment: tenes una funcion sumar array??? la creas.. y le pasas el array par o impar... segun si el usuario te dijo sumar uno u otro.. no?

Comment: si asi es , gracias por orientarme a donde llevar el problema voy intentarlo de esa forma.

Answer (score 2):

puedes solicitar que se ingrese una opción para calcular la suma de pares o impares

```java
boolean sumar_pares = true;
int suma=0;
String opcion;
do {
    System.out.println("Sumar pares -> p // Sumar impares ->i");
    opcion=sc.next();
} while(!opcion.equals("p") && !opcion.equals("i"));// un bucle en caso se ingrese una opcion diferente
```

ya teniendo la opción elegida y haciendo uso de los for que tenias para imprimir los arreglos, calculas la suma correspondiente y le cambias el valor a la variable boolean

```java
if(opcion.equals("p")) {
    sumar_pares=true;
    for(int i=0; i<conteo_pares;i++) {
        suma+=par[i];
    } 
}
else if(opcion.equals("i")) {
    sumar_pares=false;
    for(int i=0; i<conteo_impares;i++) {
        suma+=impar[i];
    }
}
```

y luego haciendo uso de la variable boolean, aplicando una condicional, imprimes la suma elegida

```java
if(sumar_pares){//si el boolean es true
    System.out.println("La suma de pares es :"+suma);
} else {//si el boolean es false
    System.out.println("La suma de impares es :"+ suma);
}
```